# Ordinal Parameter Not bound : 2 in @Query annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

I am getting following error when I try to run this query.

> org.hibernate.QueryException: Ordinal parameter not bound : 2",

```
@Query(value = "SELECT amu " +
                   "FROM Upgrade amu " +
                    "INNER JOIN FETCH amu.visibility v " +
                   " WHERE v IN ?2 " +
                    "AND amu.id= '?1' "         
   )
Optional<Upgrade> myFindMethod(final String uid, final String cid);
```

If I change  `" WHERE v IN ?2 "` with   `" WHERE v IN ?2 OR v IN ?1 "`, then it works. I have no idea why it does not work. Any idea?

Note: Visibility is type of `Set<String>` in the Upgrade class.

Comment: shouldn't that be `WHERE  ?2 MEMBER OF v` instead of `WHERE v IN ?2` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that you have only one bind parameter declared in the query but have actually two parameters in the method.

This is because in `"AND amu.id= '?1' "` what looks like a bind parameter is actually a string literal due to the enclosing quotes.
If you want that to be handled as a bind parameter remove the quotes: `"AND amu.id= ?1 "`

Answer (score 26):

To add to Jens' answer: **be aware of the spaces**!

For example, this will throw the error:

`"WHERE v IN ?2" +
 "AND amu.id= ?1 "`

And this will work fine:

`"WHERE v IN ?2 " +
 "AND amu.id= ?1 "`

It's a minute difference that's easy to overlook.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my issue!

Comment: The space.... that space !!! Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Saved me a lot of time, this one

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
My code was like that:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT amu " +
                   "FROM Upgrade amu " +
                    "INNER JOIN FETCH amu.visibility v " +
                   " WHERE v IN ?2 " +
                    "AND amu.id= ?1" +
                    "ORDER BY amu.id"            
   )
Optional<Upgrade> myFindMethod(final String uid, final String cid);
```

I forgot to put a space before double quote before passing a new line.
It causes an SQL error and doesn't see the second parameter.
I just added space and solved it.

```
"AND amu.id= ?1 " +
```