# QueryException: Ordinal parameters did not start with base 1 : 2

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Hello I am trying to filter by enum but I keep having different kinds of errors so I have switched to native query, but still encountered an error.

Here is the error: org.hibernate.QueryException: Ordinal parameters did not start with base 1 : 2
It pointed to my service method... I have googled it but there are no similar questions...

Repository:

```java
@Query(value=
"""
    SELECT mi.* 
    FROM meal_item AS mi 
    WHERE 
        (mi.meal LIKE '%?1%' OR 
        mi.note LIKE '%?1%') AND 
        (?2 IS NULL OR
        ?2 = mi.meal_size)             
""", nativeQuery=true)
List<MealItem> getAllMealItems(String search, MealItem.MealSize mealSize, Pageable pageable);
```

Service:

```java
@Override
public List<MealItem> getAllMealItems(String search, Pageable pageable) {
    return mealItemRepository.getAllMealItems(search, MealItem.MealSize.light, pageable);
}
```

MealItem enum:

```java
public enum MealSize{
    light, medium, heavy
}

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@JsonProperty("size")
@Column(name="meal_size", columnDefinition="ENUM('light','medium','heavy')", nullable=false)
private MealSize mealSize;
```

This is a new error after switching to native query...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ordinal Parameter Not bound : 2 in @Query annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958908/ordinal-parameter-not-bound-2-in-query-annotation)

Comment: Remove the quotes around the `%?1%`. So `mi.meal LIKE %?1% OR mi.note LIKE %?1%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by switching to named parameters and fixing the quotes in the query...

```
   @Query(value=
    """
        SELECT mi.* 
        FROM meal_item AS mi 
        WHERE 
            (mi.meal LIKE CONCAT('%', :s, '%') OR 
            mi.note LIKE CONCAT('%', :s, '%')) AND 
            (:#{#ms?.name()} IS NULL OR
            :#{#ms?.name()} = mi.meal_size)             
    """, nativeQuery=true)
    List<MealItem> getAllMealItems(@Param("s") String search, @Param("ms") MealItem.MealSize mealSize, Pageable pageable);
```